# How can I use seperate templates for admin and user in angular5 project?

Tags: css, node.js, templates, angular5, angular-cli

This is my `index.html` page. I am using only one index page.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Angular5</title>
  <base href="/">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes you can you would do it with the angular5 routing

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this you would use Angular 5 Routing and set two routes up one for the users and one for the admins so the users would go to `example.com` and the admins would go to `example.com/admin`

First, you would make a file called `app-routing.module.ts` and make it look like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserLayoutComponent } from './pages/user-layout/user-layout.component';
import { AdminLayoutComponent } from './pages/admin-layout/admin-layout.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './pages/home/home.component';
import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './pages/admin/dashboard.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserLayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
      // Other Links that will look like example.com/example-link
  ] },
  { path: 'admin', component: adminLayoutComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: AdminDashboardCompoent },
      // Other Links that will look like example.com/admin/example-link
  ] }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In your `app.module.ts` you will import
`import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';` then add it to your imports

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ...
    // Other Modules
],
```

Then in your `user-layout.component.html` you will add `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` where you want the content to show within the template. so if you had a menu you would do it like this. Same for the other layout file.

```
<div class="my-menu">
    ...
    // Menu content
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Links will look like this `<li routerLink="/admin">Admin Dashbord</li>` and `<li routerLink="/">Home</li>`

And the CSS you can edit on each component and then will make it so you have a separate template for each one